# ValueType "tableViewCell" has no member navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell, pushviewcontroller

I have a collectionView inside a tableView cell. I would like to tap on the collectionView cell and go to the detailTableView with the information passed in. I'm not having a lot of work. Have done some research and it states that a tableView cell has neither a storyboard or a navigationController. How would i be able to pass on the data into the detailTableView. Here is my implementation which is probably not correct

```
class PopularTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
     var books = [CKRecord]()
     var detailViewController: DetailViewController!
} 


extension PopularTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDataSource {
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let record = books[indexPath.row]
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
        if let detailVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC") as? DetailViewController {
            detailVC.bookRecord = record
           detailViewController.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You should push view controller from root view controller which contains tableview:

```
self.navigationController.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
```

Data from collection view could be passed with custom delegate, for example:

```
protocol CustomDelegate: class {
    func didSelectItem(record: CKRecord)
}

weak var delegate: CustomDelegate?

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let record = books[indexPath.row]
    delegate?.didSelectItem(record: record)
}
```

Then in tableview cell another delegate:

```
extension TableViewCell: CustomDelegate {
    func didSelectItem(record: CKRecord) {
        delegate?.didSelectItem(record: record)
    }
}
```

And finally in view controller:

```
extension ViewController: CustomDelegate {
    func didSelectItem(record: CKRecord) {
        let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Home", bundle: nil)
        if let detailVC = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DetailVC") as? DetailViewController {
            detailVC.bookRecord = record
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailVC, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Don't forget to connect delegates like:

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Comment: i'm gonna try this but the `didSelectItemAt indexPath` method is inside my tableViewCell . Everything is implemented in the `tableViewCell`. I only have a tableViewController where i just change the `displayHeaderView `

Comment: Got it, so you need just single custom delegate call from tableViewCell that notifies tableViewController

Comment: @ Alexander Kim i still can't find a reference to the properties from the cell, i have implemented the delegate method in the `didselectItem` method but this is inside the cell. where can i call the `func` like you did in extension `TableviewCell: CustomDelegate`

Comment: Custom delegate method should be implemented in tableViewController

Comment: In tableViewController `cellForRow` write `cell.delegate = self` and then implement `CustomDelegate` `didSelectItem` function inside tableViewController
You could write it as extension or just like this:
`ViewController: UITableViewController, CustomDelegate`

Comment: Got you, let me try that

Answer (score 0):

You could create a delegate on your collection view cell which would then notify the table view when it’s tapped and you could then do whatever you want after that.

Would it be simpler to just have the collection view and add a 2nd section to manage the detail view?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue in the collection view. After a little bit of trying, I realised that the concept to solve this issue is that find out the controller of those views whether they are table view or collection view, and then use this controller to navigate to the new controller.

- Declare a controller variable that can be accessed in your table view later. `var controller = ViewController()` (In my style, I prefer to write it as a global variable)
- Assign the declared controller variable to self in order to let the reference point this variable.

```
   class ViewController: UIViewController{
    
    
     override func loadView() {
        controller = self
     }  
   }
```

- Use this controller's navigation pushing method in other views in your case table view.

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
         controller.navigationController?.pushViewController(DetailViewController(), animated: true)
    }
```